# How to parallel two generators?

Tags: generator

I want to know if its possible to power a food truck( park trailer) with 2 generators to provide 110/240 with no connection to shore power provided eliminating need for transfer switch... I assume 2 gens will be paralleled for more capacity....no batteries or shore power,just constant voltage from 2 gasoline gens providing 110/240...No low voltage i.e 12vdc

Comment: You can't parallel generators.  You would need to have them each drive independent electrical circuits.  Why not just get one generator that is big enough to run everything you need?

Comment: They might be able to self-syncronize, but the devil is in the details.

Comment: There are some generators that are designed to allow parallel operation with another of the same make and model, but it would probably be better to get a single generator rated to provide the maximum power you need.

Answer (score 3):

No parallel but separate lines like split phase 2 line power and **you must add up all the power consumption from the label on each appliance being used.**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frv8io.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is what it would look like in series 60 HZ and 58 Hz with 2 dropouts every second from a 2 cycle per second error between 2 generators.

If in parallel each gen would have the wrong voltage at the same time and only match for one instant. This results in one generator loading the other to struggle with excessive load and then trip a breaker or short each other out and then you have 0 generators unless the breaker was fast enough.
[image]

I would guess limited kettle and no electric heat with all gas heating and only powered vents , 1 fridge and lights is OK for 1 gen.  But gen's come in all sizes.  And compressor-motors tend to draw 5 to 8x on startup for fridges.

You can operate two separate mismatched generators on separate circuits only or get a synch modification for each governer.